# live audio stream play with javafx

Tags: java, audio, javafx

How to play live audio with javafx.
I tried mediaplayer for audio live stream.

http://bbcmedia.ic.llnwd.net/stream/bbcmedia_radio1_mf_p  This is bbc radio stream.

But it don't play anything. who can help me? :)

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javafxapplication8;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Top1s
 */
public class JavaFXApplication8 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

     // Create and set the Scene. 

     Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 540, 209); 


     stage.setScene(scene); 


     stage.show();



     // Create the media source. The source may be an URI or local file

     // for local file

     // String source=new File("c:/abc.flv"").toURI().toString());

     String source = "http://bbcmedia.ic.llnwd.net/stream/bbcmedia_radio1_mf_p";
     // for URI file

     // String source="http:/aaa/xyz/abc.flv";



     Media media = new Media(source); 



     // Create the player and set to play automatically. 

     MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media); 

     mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true); 



     // Create the view and add it to the Scene. 

     MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer); 

     ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(mediaView); 

 }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add javafx.media to your classpath? If's not so,  it won't play any audio. To add javafx.media to your VM Options write following:

```
--module-path "\path\to\javafx-sdk\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.media
```